# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid using TryParse Method

Tags: vb.net, tryparse

I have a simple addition program in VB.Net and I am attempting to test if the textbox is only taking in a number and not any letters. I need to use the TryParse method, and I cannot figure out wny I am still receiving this error. Pls Help

```
Public Class perrySolutionForm
Dim numberOne As Double
Dim numberTwo As Double

Public Function sum(ByRef numberOne As Double, ByRef numberTwo As Double)
    sum = Val(numberOne) + Val(numberTwo)
End Function

Public Function difference(ByRef numberOne As Double, numberTwo As Double)     

difference = Val(numberOne) - Val(numberTwo)

End Function

Private Sub sumButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sumButton.Click
    If numberOneInput.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Both fields must be filled out.")
        If Double.TryParse(numberOneInput.Text, numberOne) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Success")
            'numberOne has a Double value
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Failure")
            'numberOne = Nothing
        End If
    Else
        outputLabel.Text = sum(numberOne, numberTwo)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub numberOneInput_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles numberOneInput.TextChanged
    numberOne = numberOneInput.Text

End Sub

Private Sub numberTwoInput_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles numberTwoInput.TextChanged
    numberTwo = numberTwoInput.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Quit using `Val` it is leftover Legacy code. Please convert your types before using them - i.e. `numberOne = numberOneInput.Text` = bad coding.

Comment: Could you give me an example? This is my first semester in VB.Net so I am referring to the textbook given. Thanks

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of the source code file and recompile.  Fix the bugs the compiler now tells you about.

Comment: That is what `Double.TryParse` is doing for you, it is converting you string value if poss.

Comment: Option Strict On, very good indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use the TryParse:

```
If Double.TryParse(numberOneInput.Text, numberOne) Then
  'code for a success
  'numberOne has a Double value
Else
  'code for a failure
  'numberOne = Nothing
End If
```

End the code block if text is empty:

```
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberOneInput.Text) Then 
   MessageBox.Show("Value is incorrect format")
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: So I have tried this, and the second I put a letter in numberOneInput Textbox, it still displays the "Conversion from string “” to type 'Double' is not valid". I updated the code above. Thanks

Comment: This function accepts an empty string, but will jump to the `Else` part of the if statement since it fails. Can you tell me which line of code your talking about?

Comment: The line it is complaining about is " numberOne = numberOneInput.Text". At least that is what is highlighted after the program breaks. I should note that I am not receiving neither message boxes, the program just pukes

Comment: Right, that is why you need to convert values before assigning them to the wrong type.

Comment: I am still confused as to how to convert the values before assigning them. After using "Option Explicit On" it changed  " numberOne = numberOneInput.Text". TO "numberOne = CDbl(numberOneInput.Text)". Is this what you were referring to? Because the program still pukes.

Comment: That is the default for VB to use the `CDbl` function, if you use the `Double.TryParse` this give you place for conversion success or failure where `CDbl` does not - i.e. your program blows up! You can use this technique for all the `Double` variables where they are getting text input.

Comment: So could you show me some example code as to what I am trying to do? I am really just trying to get it to work and everywhere I look, it says the same code implementation that I am using. Thanks

Comment: I did, in my answer - that is an example of converting the `String` to `Double`.

Comment: I do not need to have exact percision, as this is just a simple addition program. I have tried implementing what I think is correct up top, but the program is still puking. Any working code examples to offer?

Comment: It has nothing to do with precision. I am just teaching you how to convert types and how to do them properly so you will not get anymore "puking" from your program - as you put it. Part of programming is to learn the logic - do you want me to take that away from you and just write the whole thing for you? Sorry, I won't do that.

Comment: @Plutonix, that all depends on how much precision they need, they may only need a `Single` as far as anyone here knows.